# Models in Yii Framework?

Tags: php, yii

I build a website application using Yii Framework.

I want to use model with query like this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, u.score, (SELECT COUNT(ownerId) FROM post p WHERE p.ownerId = u.id) AS totalPost 
FROM users u 
ORDER BY u.score DESC, totalPost DESC LIMIT 10
```

Please help me to convert the query into models in Yii Framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is related chapter from "The Definite Guide To Yii" - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/database.arr

Answer (score 2):

Well I think you can simplify this by using a relation 'TotalPost' => array(self::STAT,'Post','OwnerId')

Check CStatRelation for more details. Note that in this class, the select property is the statistical expression which is by default COUNT(*).

Also, your query can be mapped into User model as long as you have a public $TotalPost; in model class User.